# Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=54 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer"

Tags: objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking to post data on server and get response.

Following is my code.

```
- (void) callLoginAPI:(NSDictionary *)dictProfile{
    // 1

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username" : [dictProfile valueForKey:@"name"],
                             @"first_name" : [dictProfile valueForKey:@"first_name"],
                             @"last_name" : [dictProfile valueForKey:@"last_name"],
                             @"email" : [dictProfile valueForKey:@"email"],
                             @"dob" : [dictProfile valueForKey:@"birthday"],
                             @"gender" : [dictProfile valueForKey:@"gender"],
                             @"location" : [[dictProfile valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"name"],
                             @"timezone" : [dictProfile valueForKey:@"timezone"],
                             @"language" : @"",
                             @"profile_pic_url" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",[dictProfile valueForKey:@"id"]]
                             };
    NSString* HOST_URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/login/",BASE_URL];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [operationManager POST:HOST_URL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        NSLog(@"resp:%@",responseObject);
        // Enter what happens here if successsful.

    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
        // Enter what happens here if failure happens

    }];
}
```

but I got following error

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=54 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer" UserInfo=0x787f0ec0 {_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://10.1.81.35:8000/api//login/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://10.1.81.35:8000/api//login/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

Can anyone tell me where I made mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: I've just come across this error on the iOS 10 beta and in my case this error is generated by NSURLConnection when the server wants a client certificate but the delegate does not provide one.  In previous versions of iOS, this just produced the "Server requires a client certificate" error.

Comment: @JoeyCarson I am having the same issue on iOS 10 public release right now, what did you do to fix this problem can you elaborate?

Comment: @satheeshwaran Is your problem the same as mine (server requiring a client certificate and delegate not providing one)?  I didn't quite the fix the problem at the time.  Instead to work around it I simply caught that error and translated it inside my API to produce the old error that it would, since we had a lot of code depending on whether this error code was returned.